# SVG Plot Area Inside absolutely positioned DIV gets shrinked

Tags: html, css, svg

How do I get blue line to connect the inner box diagonal corners (currently path's size falls short of `10px` by both width and height).

The other problem is SVG path doesn't seem to be pixel perfect. I manually increased its size by using path data to `L 810 410` and the line got shifted towards the bottom-right corner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px; width: 800px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: -10px; right: -10px; bottom: -10px; left: -10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: content-box;">
        <svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <path d="M10 10 L 800 400" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square"/>
        </svg>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much idea with SVG but I tried that changing the d value's with 
d="M10 10 L 810 410" solves your problem and now it connected diagonally completely.

Hope thiss helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'd rather find the cause of the problem.